# How do I take one word as input from the user, and print "illegal input" if there's a number or a space?

Tags: c, input

```
char word[20];
printf("Enter a word: ");
gets(word);
for(int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){
    if((word[i]>=97 && word[i]<=122) || (word[i]>=65 && word[i]<=90)){
        printf("Alphabet");
        break;
    }else{
        printf("Illegal input");
        break;
    }
}
```

Why is this wrong? I need only one word from the user. If there are any spaces or nonalphabetic characters, it must print illegal input. How do I correct this?

Comment: What problem are you having with this code ? A good question must include a description of the problem.

Comment: Your code checks only first character and ```break```.

Comment: code -> https://onlinegdb.com/BkUpDSC4P

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is not related to the *alphabetical character check*: in fact you are actually checking just the first character of the string, as **you break the loop in both the `if` and `else` branches**.

I suppose you just want to interrupt the elaboration just when an invalid character is found:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char word[20];
printf("Enter a word: ");
fgets(word, 19, stdin);

word[strcspnn(word, "\n")] = 0;

for(int i=0;i<strlen(word);i++){
    if((isalpha(word[i]))){
        printf("Alphabet");
        // break;  // No break required here!
    }else{
        printf("Illegal input");
        break;
    }
}
```

Please note how:

- I used `fgets` instead of `gets`: the latter is **deprecated** because it is unsafe. On the other hand, `fgets` is able to control the number of characters acquired, without the risk to go beyond the size of the `word` array
- Since `fgets` stores also the trailing newline, I search for it and substitute with the string terminator (as wonderfully shown [here])(https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/11336762)
- Using all those magic numbers to check the range from the characters is bad practice. You can do the same by using standard function [`isaplha()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha), contained within `ctype.h`